# heroku pkg-config install failure

Tags: node.js, heroku, apt

i'm trying to install phash on heroku using https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt. i'd like to use it in my node.js app using https://github.com/mgmtio/phash-image.

I currently have an `Aptfile`:

```
cimg-dev
libphash0-dev
libmagickcore-dev
```

However, I'm currently getting the following error:

```
remote:        > phash-image@3.0.0 install /tmp/build_52b169122dc28a567a6f55c3b892c560/node_modules/phash-image
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:        
remote:        Package pHash was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:        Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pHash.pc'
remote:        to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:        No package 'pHash' found
remote:        gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-L --libs-only-other pHash' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_52b169122dc28a567a6f55c3b892c560/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
remote:        gyp ERR! command "node" "/tmp/build_52b169122dc28a567a6f55c3b892c560/vendor/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_52b169122dc28a567a6f55c3b892c560/node_modules/phash-image
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
```

what does this mean? how do i fix it?

Comment: do you have [pHash](http://www.phash.org/) installed? and the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys! the problem was that one of my other buildpacks was messing up the config path. it has sense been fixed!

Answer (score 4):

The error says package pHash was not found in the pkg-config search path. You should add the directory containing `pHash.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. The path to pHash is unset.

Try:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

and then rebuild.

If that doesnot work

```
$ locate pHash.pc
```

this will give you a path to pHash.pc. Use the path (minus pHash.pc) and add it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH= <path_here>
```

The similar issue was raised here in [node canvas githib](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/246)